# Why does the default bullet appears instead of the image in my list-style-image property?

Tags: html, css

Unfortunately, the selected image is not appearing as a marker...
It's displaying the default disc type.
Can you point out was is wrong with the code.
The url pathway is right.
Please help.

I have cross-checked the image url several times.

```html
    <style>
    
    ul{list-style-image: url('C:\Users\Ayushi\Pictures\Saved Pictures/Bud.png');}
    
    </style>
    
    <ul>
    
    <li><b>Olanzapine</b></li>
    
    <li><b>Haloperidol</b></li>
    
    <li><b>Sertraline</b></li>
    
    </ul>
```

The image marker is not being displayed.
Instead the default disc bullet is appearing.

Comment: C:\Users\Ayushi\Pictures\Saved Pictures/Bud.png Is the address correct? The slashes look wrong to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the backward slashes to forward:

```
ul {list-style-image: url('C:/Users/Ayushi/Pictures/Saved Pictures/Bud.png');}
```

Also as a universal solution, replace `Saved Pictures` with `Saved%20Pictures` to escape white space in older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to:
`url('file://C:/Users/Ayushi/Pictures/Saved Pictures/Bud.png')`